# Why MassTransit `ServiceCollectionBusConfigurator` doesn't add `IConsumer` to `DI` by `AddConsumer`?

Tags: dependency-injection, masstransit

I am working on `Blazor Server` `.NET 5` project which uses a nice `MassTransit` `7.0.5-develop2976` framework (thanks [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1882/chris-patterson) by the way!).

I am curious **why `MassTransit` `ServiceCollectionBusConfigurator` doesn't add consumers to DI** when I do `.AddConsumer<T>()`. As a result, I am getting "**Unable to resolve consumer type...**" exception like below. See the workaround below.

For instance, similar `ServiceCollectionMediatorConfigurator` does it when if I add my `IConsumer<>` type via it.

An example of the exception I am getting when `MassTransit` tries to resolve my consumer (in my case it happens when a recurring scheduled job is triggered, but it doesn't matter).

```
MassTransit.ConsumerException: Unable to resolve consumer type 'SomeMyConsumer'.
         at MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration.ScopeProviders.DependencyInjectionConsumerScopeProvider.MassTransit.Scoping.IConsumerScopeProvider.GetScope[TConsumer,T](ConsumeContext`1 context)
         at MassTransit.Scoping.ScopeConsumerFactory`1.Send[TMessage](ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
         at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
```

**The question: what is the reason for such behaviour from an architectural perspective?** Am I missing anything?

Comment: It absolutely should add your consumers to the container. If you have a reproducible case, let me know. The unit tests all pass, so it has to be registered.

Comment: This exception happens when a scheduled recurring message is sent to the bus queue (RabbitMQ transport) which is a receiving endpoint for this consumer. I am super busy with my current coding stuff, so can't prepare a repro-package. If you'd like - we could make a quick shared screen call - I will show you. Would you @ChrisPatterson?

Comment: No, I don't believe it's an issue with MassTransit, so unless you can show it in a failing unit test or something, I'm going to let it go for now.

Comment: I'm actually seeing this today with 7.2.1 - I'll open a discussion in the repo.

Comment: [Linked the discussion](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions/2781) for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a **workaround**, if you explicitly add your consumer to `IServiceCollection` like in the example below - the error disappears, of course:

```
services.AddScoped<SomeMyConsumer>();
```

... or even just register the same consumer via `ServiceCollectionMediatorConfigurator` as well:

```
services.AddMediator(configurator =>
{
    configurator.AddConsumer<SomeMyConsumer>();
});
```

P.S. IMHO, similar abstractions should behave similarly if they use the same method signature, aren't they?